# is Asynchronous Processing=true required?

Tags: .net, ado.net, npgsql

When connecting to a SQL Server `Asynchronous Processing=true` is required in the connection string to enable true async support, is the same true for Npgsql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is a SQL Server-specific connection string parameter which doesn't exist in Npgsql (you will get an error). Npgsql's supported connection string parameters [are listed here](http://www.npgsql.org/doc/connection-string-parameters.html).

By the way, `Asynchronous Processing` doesn't seem to do anything on SQL Server anymore either, [see the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/asynchronous-programming).